# Popping Navigation Stack with android back button

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-navigation

I am trying to navigate backwards in my flutter app using the android back button, the issue being that I can't pop the navigation and pass data like the traditional pop method. I have been able to do this fine using the normal button on press but I don't want to disable the back button incase it passes data incorrectly.

> Navigator.pop(context, {'state': 'update'});

I looked into and attempted using the NavigatorPopHandler but this function doesn't even get called when I try and return to the previous page.

I also tried using the PopScope class but this only returns errors but will print debug statements, when I get it to run after a bit of time/interaction with the app this is the error I get

`════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4782 pos 12: '!\_debugLocked': is not true.`

any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution I found, I believe by blocking the canPop and checking if the navigation has popped it removes the default race condition. Hope this helps someone.
[Flutter PopScore Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html)

```
return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }
        debugPrint("here");
        Navigator.pop(
            context, {'state': 'update'});
      },
```